# Load jquery widget dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, widget

In my application, I’m creating an html table and displaying it as a jquery datatable. While forming a html table content, I have added a script to a particular column for all rows. The purpose of that script is to load the load the content from widget jquery library on mouse hover of particular cell. *That widget is company internal one which is used to show person details on hover of name.*

As number of rows is reaching to 40 or more, the page load is becoming very slow and it gives warning message in IE8 – “Stop running this script? A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.”
Is there any way we can improve the page performance? Can we add the script dynamically and refresh a particular cell on hover of that cell?

Comment: Are you fetching the information on page load or the info is the HTML and simply show and hides on hover?

Comment: I'm loading the widget content on page load. After loading the data, person details pops-up on hover of person's name. I checked the html being created on hover of name, it's creating div dynamically and showing that div (having person details)